# Postman post form data as json object

Tags: post, postman

I have this json data

```
{
    "title":"title",
    "description":"title",
    "floor": 1,
    "floor_count": 10,
    "address" : {
        "street": "street",
        "house_no": "8/1",
        "door_no": "10",
        "city":"Horsens",
        "country": "Denmark",
        "postal_code":8700
    },
    "report": null
   
}
```

I want the report to include some file fields, to post files is achievable using form-data
but using form data to post files wont count those files as a report fields.

```
{
    "title":"title",
    "description":"title",
    "floor": 1,
    "floor_count": 10,
    "address" : {
        "street": "street",
        "house_no": "8/1",
        "door_no": "10",
        "city":"Horsens",
        "country": "Denmark",
        "postal_code":8700
    },
    "report": {
         "file1": file1,
         "file2": file2,
    }
   
}
```

I am trying like this, no success

[image]

Comment: Your second example, as written, isn't valid JSON. Do you want the file *content* to be added to those fields, as a string? And what exactly do you mean by "form-data"?

Comment: updated post, hope it clears out everything

Comment: i need to post a file that is nested in an object

Comment: A JSON parser has no idea what a "file" is; the only way it could work would be by having the entire contents of the file as a string, probably encoded with something like base64. Is that what your API expects?